# How to Update GridView after PostBack occurred by a control outside GridView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, postback

I have a `GridView`, which is to be updated when User Clicks on a Button outside this `GridView`, a `GridView` Column should be updated for a particular Row. 
So I m biding new Data for `GridView` in `PostBack`. But as We know `PostBack` is called before the `OnClick` Button Event. So `GridView` is bound at this time. But I want the update `GridView` column value for a particular row based on the some operations in `OnClick` Button Event. 
So I tried to bind the `GridView` in `OnClick` Button Event also. But its not getting updated.
So my main doubt is.

Is this possible to pass value in a method which is being called in `PostBack` Block from the Click Event which a causing the `PostBack`?

```
private void bindTheGriView()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataRow dr = null;
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Row Number", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("POS Id", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Action", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Status", typeof(string)));
        for (int index = 0; index < m_listStrPendingListOfPOS.Count; index++)
        {
            dr = dt.NewRow();
            int iRowNo = index + 1;
            dr["Row Number"] = iRowNo;
            string strGridViewPOSId = m_listStrPendingListOfPOS[index];
            dr["POS Id"] = strGridViewPOSId;
            dr["Action"] = string.Empty;
            //check for the flag. if the flag is true set status to Pending else to Associated
            dr["Status"]=((Label)GridViewMultiplePOSAssociationId.Rows[index].FindControl("LabelStatusPendingPOSId")).Text;
           dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }

        ViewState["POSTable"] = dt;
        GridViewMultiplePOSAssociationId.DataSource = dt;
        GridViewMultiplePOSAssociationId.DataBind();
    }


    protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool statusFlag=false;
    if (ViewState["RowIndexPOS"] != null)
    {
        int iRowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["RowIndexPOS"]);
        Label lblStatus = (Label)GridViewMultiplePOSAssociationId.Rows[iRowIndex].FindControl("LabelStatusPendingPOSId");
        //Means all rows in GridView are successfully associated
        if (table.Rows.Count == iResultCount)
        {
            lblStatus.Text = "Associated";
        }
        else
        {
            lblStatus.Text = "Pending";
        }
    }
    //now call the binding method with the bool flag value
     bindTheGriView();
}
```

No, I'm not using Update Panel.

Comment: Could you show some code of the gridview and the button click event?

Comment: Post some code AND tell us if you can use UpdatePanels or not.  The answer will depend on whether UpdatePanels are an option.

Comment: Modified the question.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do it in the postback. Abstract your data bind into a method and call that method from the appropriate events.

```
public void BindMyData()
{
    // Do data bindings on all bound controls
}

public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
        BindMyData();
}

public void myClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Update the data in the repository


    BindMyData();
}
```

Alternatively, you could move your databinding to the `Page_PreRender` event to ensure that it always binds after any controls have acted.